# Software type for processing an author's works

Tags: text-processing, text-search, academia

I look for a category of software, not concrete software packages. Of course if you name some, that wouldn't hurt.

I am to process the works of an author. In the past century this was called writing Zettels. To collect the most important statements of the author in the form of notes.

I could do this with a simple text file, writing the quotes and my remarks, possibly keywords, and then use standard search tools when I write my paper.

But I guess people have created more sophisticated software tools for this. Is there a category of software for this purpose?

Comment: "note-taking and productivity tools", perhaps. What do you mean by "standard search tools"? The `grep` command line tool?  Do you prefer to work with a GUI based tool? which OS? free or commercial? Sole use or collaboration with others? ...

Comment: Yes, grep is a standard search tool or vim's regular expression search which is basically the same.

Comment: Processing **how**? Just noting down random facts? No idea what "Zettels" are either, unless it's German for postits, but they're also used nowadays. Please use English terminology.